# Angle in minimum_rotated_rectangle

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I have a simple question, but I can't find the answer
I am looking for the principal angle of a `minimum_rotated_rectangle` polygon in relation to a latitude or a longitude.

```
df4.minimum_rotated_rectangle
```

Does anyone have this in stock?

Comment: Please check this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/380505/29431.

Comment: perfect Thank you